# What does this %1$@%2$d format specifier means in objective c

Tags: objective-c, format-specifiers

I've been working with format specifiers but they were generic like `%d` or `%@` but today in a tutorial I saw these `%1$@%2$d` and didn't understand what they represent.
It was a calculator example so they are using them in this statement: `stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1$@%2$d",stack,number];`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The numbers represent positional parameters.  The parameters which follow the format string are slotted into the string based on their position in the parameters list.  The first parameter goes into the %1 slot, the second into the %2 slot, and so on.  The purpose is to deal with languages where the order of terms/words/etc might change from your default.  You can't change the parameter order at runtime, but you can make sure the parameters end up in the correct place in the string.

**Example**

```
NSLog(@"%1$@, %2$@", @"Red", @"Blue");
NSLog(@"%2$@, %1$@", @"Red", @"Blue");
```

*Output*

```
Red, Blue
Blue, Red
```

Note that the format string changed, but the parameters are in the same order.

Comment: I see. But why we're using `$` sign?

Comment: This is awesome, I never knew this!

Comment: The $ is part of the positional.  I just left them out of my example.  A typo of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

So your format specifier **%1$@ %2$d** means:

**%1$@** for **%@**(Objective-C object) with **first parameter** and

**%2$d** for **%d***(Signed 32-bit integer (int))* with **second parameter**.

This $0, $1, $2 are shorthand parameter names like in Closures

“Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.”

Comment: This has nothing to do with closures. OP is using Objective-C, but that's not relevant here either. The $1, $2, etc. are positional specifiers, as defined by the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was thinking about them from my perspective of usage in Swift. You give the original meaning! :)